# R : error message for data.frame() element class

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use the `eventstudies` package but I get a strange error message when running the function despite following the instructions [here](https://lamfo-unb.github.io/2017/08/17/Teste-de-Eventos-en/).
My code is such as :

```
> datesevents <-data.frame("name"=c("Aaa negative","Aaa stable","Aaa negative ", "Aa1 stable", "Aa1 stable"), "Date"=c("2012-02-13","2014-0-28","2015-10-23", "2016-06-24","2018-05-25"))
> datesevents$name<-as.character(datesevents$name)
> datesevents$Date<-as.character(datesevents$Date)
> fiveCDS <- read.csv(file.choose())
> colnames(fiveCDS)<-c("Date", "Austria")
> dataCDS <- c(NA,diff(log(as.numeric(fiveCDS$Austria)), lag=1))
> fiveCDS$CDS = dataCDS
> datazoo <- read.zoo(fiveCDS)
> eventstudy(firm.returns = datazoo, event.list = datesevents, event.window = 5,type = "constantMeanReturn", to.remap = TRUE, remap = "cumsum", inference = TRUE, inference.strategy = "bootstrap", model.args = NULL)
```

And I get the following message

```
Error in phys2eventtime(z = returns$firm.returns, events = event.list[i,  : 
  events$when should be one of 'Date' or 'date-time' classes.
```

So, from my understing it means that the 2 columns with the dates in my `data.frame()` isn't considered as a class of dates ?
In any case, how can I fix this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Almost all R classes have an `as.class()` function. You are already using `as.character`. To make something `Date` class, use `as.Date`. Try `datesevents$Date = as.Date(datesevents$Date)`. You can find help by entering `?Date` (general Date class) or `?as.Date` (converting to Date class).

Comment: @Gregor Thank it seems to work, but now I have new error message for `datazoo` (new message error is `Error in eventstudy(firm.returns = datazoo, event.list = datesevents,  : 
  firm.returns should be a zoo series with at least one column. Use '[' with 'drop = FALSE'.`, should update my question, or create a new question ?

Comment: I'd just update the question with "I tried converting to Date class and then this happened..."

Comment: @Gregor, it's ok finally I've managed to fix this thank you very for your help! how can I vote for your response to be the best ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need the `Date` column to be of the class `Date` as well. Try

```
datesevents$Date = as.Date(datesevents$Date)
```

See `?Date` for info about the Date class, and `?as.Date` for info about the conversion function.